# Datarow Issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a data row i am passing the value to datarow .I want to check the length of the datarow .Pls help me to do this.

```
MastersClient ProdType = new MastersClient();
DataSet ds = ProdType.GetProductType();
DataRow[] drProduct = ds.Tables[0].Select("ProductTypeCode =" + txtProductTypeCode.Value);
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: If the value that you want to compare is stored in `txtProductTypeCode.Value`, why don't you compare that with 21? If it's in another column of the table, in which column? Do you expect that `DataTable.Select` returns multiple rows or only one at the maximum? So you see the question is not clear at all.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  I have edited the question

Comment: A `DataRow` has no "length", you want to check the length of the `DataRow[]`(array). It has a `Length`-property. But you should try to explain your next question better ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "txtProductTypeCode" ??? in the below code, if it is string you need to check in the condition using quotes

```
MastersClient ProdType = new MastersClient();
DataSet ds = ProdType.GetProductType();
DataRow[] drProduct = ds.Tables[0].Select("ProductTypeCode ='" + txtProductTypeCode.Value+"'")
if(drProduct.Length>0)
{
   if(drProduct[0]["column name"].ToString()=="21")
   {
       // your code to do based on the condition
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess that `ProductTypeCode` is an `int`. However, OP has not told much but he didn't mention an issue with `Select`.

Comment: Please do check the Datarow variable contains values length greater than 0